# How to force usage of protocol default extension "override"?

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a protocol with PAT that provides a default implementation in an extension.
Then, a class conforming that protocol provides an "override".
This override is not called, and the compiler "prefers" the default.

```
//---- Definition of the protocol with a default implentation, because I am forced to.

protocol Bag: AnyObject {
    associatedtype BagObject
    
    func add(_ e: BagObject)
}

extension Bag where BagObject: Equatable {
    //    I here give a default implementation, because I can't do differently, as this
    //    is an extension, and it is an extension because it only applies to assoicated
    //    types that are Equatables
    func contains(_ e: BagObject) -> Bool { 
        print("Default implementation is called")
        return false 
    }
}

///---- Definition of a class that gives a concrete implementation of the protocol

class BagConcreteImplementation<BagObject>: Bag {
    var bag = Array<BagObject>()
    func add(_ e: BagObject) { bag.append(e) }
}

extension BagConcreteImplementation where BagObject: Equatable {
    //    I here give a concrete implementation when the generic type is Equatable
    func contains(_ e: BagObject) -> Bool { 
        print("Concrete implementation is called")
        return bag.contains(e) 
    }
}



///---- This is a class that encapsulate a bag, in real life, this class is adding some filtering to objects that can be added to the bag

class AClassThatHaveABag<BagType: Bag> {
    typealias BagObject = BagType.BagObject
    
    let myBag: BagType
    init(bag: BagType) { myBag = bag }
}

extension AClassThatHaveABag where BagType.BagObject: Equatable {
    func contains(_ e: BagObject) {
        //    The problem here is that the compiler only knows that myBag is a Bag
        // of Int and therefore calls the default implementation
        //    It does not call the concrete implementation of the concrete class that WILL be provided
        myBag.contains(e)
    }
}



let aBagOfInt    = BagConcreteImplementation<Int>()
let objectThatContainsABagOfInt = AClassThatHaveABag(bag: aBagOfInt)

aBagOfInt.contains(0)
objectThatContainsABagOfInt.contains(0)

// Prints
// Concrete implementation is called
// Default implementation is called
```

We can clearly see the direct call is call the concrete implementation, while the encapsulated call is calling the default implementation.

How to do to make sure the concrete implementation is always called, even through an encapsulation ?

Comment: Can you show us the call site of the `BagConcreteImplementation.contains` function

Comment: @EmilioPelaez not sure to get your question. `BagConcreteImplementation.contains` is called at `aBagOfInt.contains(0)` and prints `Concrete implementation is called`.

Comment: My bad, didn't notice the scroll bar ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a few things, and somehow this works:

Declare `contains` in the protocol, not in an extension, like this:

```
func contains<T>(_ e: T) -> Bool where T: Equatable, T == BagObject
```

If you do things like `T == BagObject` in a class, a compiler error will show up saying that this makes `T` redundant, but apparently this is okay in a protocol.

Then, implement the default implementation like this:

```
extension Bag {
    func contains<T>(_ e: T) -> Bool where T: Equatable, T == BagObject {
        print("Default implementation is called")
        return false
    }
}
```

Then, you can just implement the concrete implementation directly in the class, *as a non-generic method*.

```
class BagConcreteImplementation<BagObject> : Bag {
    func contains(_ e: BagObject) -> Bool where BagObject : Equatable {
        print("Concrete implementation is called")
        return bag.contains(e)
    }
    
    var bag = Array<BagObject>()
    func add(_ e: BagObject) { bag.append(e) }
}
```

Without changing the call site, the code would print:

```
Concrete implementation is called
Concrete implementation is called
```

Comment: Without declaring the function in the protocol, the compiler has no way to connect the 2 implementations (to know that one is "overriding" the other) given the fact that `AClassThatHaveABag` only knows that `BagType` is implementing `Bag` protocol. So, this is definitely not a compiler issue.

Comment: @gcharita Well I know _that_. What is weird to me is that somehow a non-generic method is acting as the witness of a generic protocol requirement. Was that always possible?

Comment: @Sweeper I get the right result only if I remove the extension with the default implementation. If I keep it , I still get the default implementation called. But that's already a way forward, because there is now a way to remove the default, which wasn't the case. I'll accept the answer if nothing else comes in.

Comment: @AirXygène Huh that's weird. Are you using Swift 5.5?

Comment: You were faster then me. My bad, I incorrectly copied the default implementation you gave. All's OK. thanks !

Comment: @Sweeper you are right, now I see. Yes, this is indeed weird.

Comment: @gcharita Seems like this was a thing since Swift 3. If it were a bug then I would have imagined someone definitely would have fixed it at some point in all those years. I don't know which SE proposal proposed it though.

Comment: @Sweeper interestingly you can use non generic function in the default implementation but again you have the same issue. It's like the compiler prefers to call the first non generic implementation that it finds.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of completeness, I post here another solution, which avoids the use of `T == BagObject` which I find (my humble opinion) not that clean.

The idea is to use a specialized version of `Bag`, called `BagOfEquatables`, and extend the classes

```
protocol Bag: AnyObject {
    associatedtype BagObject
    func add(_ e: BagObject)
}

// Specialized version of Bag for Equatables
protocol BagOfEquatables: Bag where BagObject: Equatable{
    func contains(_ e: BagObject) -> Bool
}

extension BagOfEquatables {
    func contains(_ e: BagObject) -> Bool {
        print("Default implementation is called")
        return false
    }
}

///---- Definition of a class that gives a concrete implementation of the protocol

class BagConcreteImplementation<BagObject>: Bag {
    var bag = Array<BagObject>()
    func add(_ e: BagObject) { bag.append(e) }
}

extension BagConcreteImplementation: BagOfEquatables where BagObject: Equatable {
    func contains(_ e: BagObject) -> Bool  {
        print("Concrete implementation is called")
        return bag.contains(e)
    }
}

///---- This is a class that encapsulate a bag

class AClassThatHaveABag<BagType: Bag> {
    typealias BagObject = BagType.BagObject
    let myBag: BagType
    init(bag: BagType) { myBag = bag }
}

extension AClassThatHaveABag where  BagType: BagOfEquatables {
    func contains(_ e: BagObject) -> Bool  {
        myBag.contains(e)
    }
}



let aBagOfInt    = BagConcreteImplementation<Int>()
let objectThatContainsABagOfInt = AClassThatHaveABag(bag: aBagOfInt)

aBagOfInt.contains(0)
objectThatContainsABagOfInt.contains(0)


// Prints
// Concrete implementation is called
// Concrete implementation is called
```

Comment: In this approach, `BagOfEquatables` should not have a default implementation. You want the compiler to tell you if a `BagOfEquatables` conforming type fails to implement `contains(_:)`, not a run time message.

Comment: Good point ! (And thanks for your clarification on the other answer too).

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> This override is not called, and the compiler "prefers" the default.

The issue is that you have supplied the default implementation of the method in the extension, but never declared it as part of the protocol, itself. As a result, the compiler will use “static dispatch”.

If you include the method in the protocol, the compiler will use “dynamic dispatch” to resolve which method to call.

For a discussion of static vs. dynamic dispatch see WWDC 2016 [Understanding Swift Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/?time=1083).

---

For example:

```swift
protocol Foo {
    // without this declaration, this will use static dispatch;
    // uncomment the following line for dynamic dispatch

    // func foo()
}

extension Foo {
    func foo() {
        print("default")
    }
}

struct Bar: Foo {
    func foo() {
        print("bar implementation")
    }
}

let bar: Foo = Bar()
bar.foo()               // “default” with static dispatch; ”bar implementation“ with dynamic dispatch
```

Comment: I agree with your statement, but the `contains` method needs to be part of the protocol only if `BagObject` is `Equatable`, so it can't be part of the original protocol, and I don't think there is a way to extend without providing a default implementation. Have a look at the accepted answer and my other answer to see how they solve the issue. Thanks for having spent some of your time :-).

Comment: You misunderstand my point. Sweeper’s answer offers one particular solution, namely to add the `contains` declaration to the protocol definition in addition to a default implementation. In that answer, he describes _what_ you should do, but not _why._ I am merely clarifying (and answering the titular question) to explain _why_ the default implementation is getting called and how to make sure the concrete implementation’s rendition is called (the static vs dynamic dispatch issue). You are now asking why you need that default implementation at all but that wasn't your original question.